# Is this an objective-c memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks

I know that if you do the following you most certainly have a memory leak:

```
id foo = [[NSObject alloc] init];
foo = nil;
```

But, what if you're using self.foo, a property with retain? And your code instead looks like the following:

```
foo = [[NSObject alloc] init];
self.foo = nil;
```

Is that still a memory leak since the accessor releases the memory first before setting it to nil?

Answer (score 4):

`self.foo = nil` would translate into

```
[nil retain]
[foo release]
foo = nil
```

There is no memory leak here.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, the second example is not a memory leak. In fact, that's how I deal with `retain` properties in my `dealloc` method. It's just a lot cleaner.

The only thing you have to be careful about is making sure not to write

```
self.foo = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

or else you'll double-retain the object and end up with a memory leak.

Comment: Keep in mind using properties in dealloc is usually discouraged in case the accessor method is changed to modify another ivar (which might have already been released). I just use release instead.

Comment: @Alex: +1 for an excellent warning, but -1 for the suggestion to use self.foo = nil in a dealloc method!

Comment: @eJames self.foo = nil is the way Apple were recommending doing it in the dealloc method originally and is everywhere in their sample code.

Comment: I think for run-of-the-mill @synthesize accessors, the property syntax is the way to go. It's good enough for Apple! My thinking is, why spend two lines doing what you could do in one?

Comment: Properties in Obj-C 2 look nice, but they add complexity - especially when you can mix and match. I think they should have gone further. Maybe we will will get there in another 15 years with ObjC 3.

Answer (score 1):

Properties make it your code look like assignment, but in reality they're the same as traditional accessor methods you might have written yourself prior to Obj-C 2.0. With properties Obj-C is simply generating the accessor methods behind the scenes for you instead using the keywords you specify in the declaration (assuming you use @synthesize and don't write your own accessor methods anyway).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no memory leak. The code in your second example is logically equivalent to

```
foo = [[NSObject alloc] init];
[nil retain];
[foo release];
foo = nil;
```

because the @synthesized setter is logicall equivalent to

```
- (void)setFoo:(id)newFoo {
  [newFoo retain];
  [foo release];
  foo = newFoo;
}
```

It's worth noting that setting `foo` directly is probably not something you want to do outside of an init method. If you assign a value to `foo` directly, you bypass the automatic KVO notification (you would have to wrap your assignment in a `willChangeValueForKey:/didChangeValueForKey:` pair) *and* you break any subclass' behavior if it overrides the `setFoo:` method, expecting all modifications of `foo` to go through the setter.

You assign directly to `foo` in an init method because the `setFoo:` method or a subclass' overriden `setFoo:` method may have side-effects or depend on the instance's fully initialized.

Similarly, you would use `[foo release]` rather than `self.foo = nil;` in the `-dealloc` method for the same reasons.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers so far assume that “`foo`” in the first line of the second example is the instance variable behind the `foo` property. This is the default behavior.

If the `foo` that the first line assigns to is a local variable, then the `foo` property is irrelevant, and you will leak the object unless you release it later in the method.

If `foo` is an instance variable, but the `foo` property is actually backed by a different instance variable, or no instance variable at all, then (a) you are writing hard-to-maintain code and (b) it may be a leak.

Finally, echoing the previous answers: If `foo` is the instance variable backing the `foo` property, then this is not a leak, since the `setFoo:` method that you call in the second line will release the object that you put in the `foo` instance variable in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so as by doing `self.foo = nil` you are essentially using the setter and getting the memory management along for free.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody else seems to have noticed: **There *might be* a leak.**

I'll assume that `foo` is  both an ivar and a `retain` property:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
  NSObject * foo;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject * foo;
@end
```

Let's say your code looks something like this:

```
-(void)bar {
  foo = [[NSObject alloc] init];
  self.foo = nil;
}
```

That, in itself does not leak *provided `foo` was nil to start with*. That doesn't mean it won't leak — let's say you add some more code:

```
-(void)baz {
  self.foo = [[NSObject new] autorelease];
}

-(void)fubar {
  [self baz];
  [self bar];
}
```

Stuff like `foo = [[Foo alloc] init]` is generally safe in `init`-methods because it's assumed that you only call one of them, so `foo` is guaranteed to be `nil` initially. Everywhere else, you have to be a bit more careful.

```
// Use assertions so it crashes debug builds if it's already set
assert(!foo);
foo = [[NSObject alloc] init];
self.foo = nil;

// Or release explicitly.
[foo release];
foo = [[NSObject alloc] init];
self.foo = nil;

// Or just use the setter, which will do the "right thing".
// This is particularly relevant for "copy" or "assign" accessors.
self.foo = [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
self.foo = nil;
```